# I don't understand why my code for bubble sort does not work

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, bubble-sort

```
for (int index = 0; index < size -1; index ++) {
    for (int index2 = 0; index2 < size - index; index2 ++) {
        if (index2 != (size - index) && array[index2] > array[index2 + 1] ) {
           store = array[index2 + 1];
          array[index2 + 1] = array[index2];
          array[index2] = store;
          printf ("%d",array[index2]);
          swap ++;
          comparison ++;
        }
    }
}
```

So this is the code for swapping and comparing the element of arrays using bubble sort algorithm. It works for all cases but except with an array with two elements.
I used C for this program. I used pointer to declare the array.

For example:

```
input: [2,0],
output: [0,1]

intput: [3.8],
output: [3,1]
```

Comment: index2 + 1 may be euqal to size (index = 0). You are reading out of bounds element with array[index2 + 1].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it off by one error. Based on your code, the 2nd loop should be

```
for (int index2 = 0; index2 < size - index -1; index2 ++){ ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for(i=1;i<n;++i)
for(j=0;j<(n-i);++j)
if(a[j]>a[j+1])
{
 temp=a[j];
 a[j]=a[j+1];
 a[j+1]=temp;
}
```

where n = "size of array"
      a[] = array

Answer (score 0):

The first examples of input to output move the 0 to the first position because the if statement is true array[index2] > array[index2 + 1] .  The next example dose not pass this part of the argument making the if argument return a false statement (so it never moves the 8 to the 3 spot. Next, issue I see is that the loop runs and asks for a value that is not part of the array. Example Array[2] = 3,4; so when you have Array[count + 1] when count = 2, you are grabbing what ever the next set of bits, that are required to fill your variable. This is why you are getting trash output. Hope this helps. I would suggest make the loop stop before it gets a value that is not there.

```
 #include "stdlib.h"   // includes _countof() returns the number of elements in the array
 Array[2] = 1,2;
 for(element = 0; _countof(array) != element && ...; element++) 
 {
 }
```

_countof(array) returns 2
This part will replace the first part of your second for loop. It will stop the loop before it continues past the limits of the array, no matter what size it is. 
Add the other parts to this argument and good luck hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of the bubble sort algorithm

```
#include <stdio.h>

int bubbleSort( int *array )
{


    for (int c = 0 ; c < ( n - 1 ); c++)
    {
        for (int d = 0 ; d < n - c - 1; d++)
        {
            if (array[d] > array[d+1]) /* For decreasing order use < */
            {
                int swap       = array[d];
                array[d]   = array[d+1];
                array[d+1] = swap;
            }
       }
   }

   return 0;
}
```

However, if I were to implement it, I would use three exclusive-OR statements to implement the swap, as then the swap variable would not be needed. And it would be a lot faster

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He's asking why his code doesn't work. Just an example of a bubble sort with no explanation of what it does differently than the OP's code doesn't shed light on the issue.